# How to convert a canvas to a png file?

Tags: canvas, cypress

I want to convert a `canvas` to a `png` file and save it in order to do comparison tests with Cypress. The problem is that the file I create is empty.

```js
cy.get('#imgcanv').as('canvas');
cy.get('@canvas').then((cnv) => {
url = cnv[0].toDataURL('image/png');
cy.log(cnv); // OK

const data = url.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, '')
cy.writeFile('first-image.png', data, 'base64');
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have here is that `cy.writeFile` need to run in the node context, not JavaScript.

For that you need to create a task in your plugin file that wraps this call. Then just call the task instead, something like

```
cy.task('writeFile', {filename, data})
```